# Interuption with pic16f18875 microcontroleur

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplab

i'm currently trying to use a button as an interrupt. But i'm struggling with it. I've seen in the datasheet that i should enable: INTE bit of PIE0, INTEDG of INTCON, AND GIE if PIE.
I've also seen that i have to use the INTPPS register to configure a pin to be the interrupt, so as i want to use RB0 as an interupt, then i used PIR0bits.INTF to check if the interupt= true in my ISR. I did that :

```
void ledLoop(unsigned char *ptr){
    unsigned char *tmp = ptr;
    while(*tmp<64){
        LATB = *tmp;
         *tmp *= 2;
         __delay_ms(200);
    }
}

void __interrupt() high_isr(void){
    INTCONbits.GIE = 0;
    if( PIR0bits.INTF){
        LATB = ~LATB;
        PIR0bits.INTF = 0; 
    }
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
}

void launch(void){
    unsigned char run = 1;
    while(1){
        if(PORTDbits.RD7==1){
            unsigned char tmp = 1;
            ledLoop(&tmp);
        }
        if(PORTDbits.RD6==1){
            LATB=0xff;
        }
      
        
        else{
            LATB=0;
        }
    }
}
void main(void)
{
    ANSELDbits.ANSD7=0;
    ANSELDbits.ANSD6=0;
    TRISB=0;
    TRISA=0;
    LATA=0x00;
    TRISDbits.TRISD7=1;
    TRISDbits.TRISD6=1;
    
    TRISBbits.TRISB0=1;
    
     //GIE: Global Interrupt Enable bit
    //PEIE: Peripheral Interrupt Enable bit
    PIE0bits.INTE = 1;
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
    INTCONbits.INTEDG = 1;
    INTPPSbits.INTPPS = 0x08;
  
    launch();   
}
```

Any idea of what is wrong ?

using :

- MPLABX IDE
- XC8 Compiler
- PIC16F18875

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three thing wrong with the code you posted:

1. No configuration words, so code will not build as posted
2. Changing the GIE bit inside of an ISR
3. PORTB pin RB0 not configured for digital input

See my comments using /*  */ for your code fixed:

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: dan1138
 *
 * Created on September 24, 2020, 2:23 PM
 */

// PIC16F18875 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FEXTOSC = OFF    // External Oscillator mode selection bits (Oscillator not enabled)
#pragma config RSTOSC = HFINT32 // Power-up default value for COSC bits (HFINTOSC with OSCFRQ= 32 MHz and CDIV = 1:1) (FOSC = 32 MHz))
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable bit (CLKOUT function is disabled; i/o or oscillator function on OSC2)
#pragma config CSWEN = ON       // Clock Switch Enable bit (Writing to NOSC and NDIV is allowed)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (FSCM timer enabled)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // Master Clear Enable bit (MCLR pin is Master Clear function)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config LPBOREN = OFF    // Low-Power BOR enable bit (ULPBOR disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out reset enable bits (Brown-out reset disabled)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (VBOR) set to 1.9V on LF, and 2.45V on F Devices)
#pragma config ZCD = OFF        // Zero-cross detect disable (Zero-cross detect circuit is disabled at POR.)
#pragma config PPS1WAY = OFF    // Peripheral Pin Select one-way control (The PPSLOCK bit can be set and cleared repeatedly by software)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a reset)

// CONFIG3
#pragma config WDTCPS = WDTCPS_31// WDT Period Select bits (Divider ratio 1:65536; software control of WDTPS)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // WDT operating mode (WDT Disabled, SWDTEN is ignored)
#pragma config WDTCWS = WDTCWS_7// WDT Window Select bits (window always open (100%); software control; keyed access not required)
#pragma config WDTCCS = SC      // WDT input clock selector (Software Control)

// CONFIG4
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // UserNVM self-write protection bits (Write protection off)
#pragma config SCANE = available// Scanner Enable bit (Scanner module is available for use)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (Low Voltage programming enabled. MCLR/Vpp pin function is MCLR.)

// CONFIG5
#pragma config CP = OFF         // UserNVM Program memory code protection bit (Program Memory code protection disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // DataNVM code protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection disabled)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ (32000000ul)

void ledLoop(unsigned char *ptr){
    unsigned char *tmp = ptr;
    while(*tmp<64){
        LATB = *tmp;
         *tmp *= 2;
         __delay_ms(200);
    }
}

void __interrupt() high_isr(void){
    //INTCONbits.GIE = 0;  /* <= do not do this in an interrupt service routine */
    if((PIE0bits.INTE) && ( PIR0bits.INTF)){ /* check that the interrupt is enabled AND asserted */
        LATB = ~LATB;
        PIR0bits.INTF = 0; 
    }
    //INTCONbits.GIE = 1;  /* <= do not do this in an interrupt service routine */
}

void launch(void){
    unsigned char run = 1;
    while(1){
        if(PORTDbits.RD7==1){
            unsigned char tmp = 1;
            ledLoop(&tmp);
        }
        if(PORTDbits.RD6==1){
            LATB=0xff;
        }
      
        
        else{
            LATB=0;
        }
    }
}
void main(void)
{
    ANSELDbits.ANSD7=0;
    ANSELDbits.ANSD6=0;
    TRISB=0;
    TRISA=0;
    LATA=0x00;
    TRISDbits.TRISD7=1;
    TRISDbits.TRISD6=1;
    
    TRISBbits.TRISB0=1;
    ANSELBbits.ANSB0=0; /* make RB0 a digital input */
    
     //GIE: Global Interrupt Enable bit
    //PEIE: Peripheral Interrupt Enable bit
    PIE0bits.INTE = 1;
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
    INTCONbits.INTEDG = 1;
    INTPPSbits.INTPPS = 0x08; /* assign INT input to RB0 */
  
    launch();   
}
```